# Cannot change Safari default browser

Tags: macos, safari, macos-mojave

I'm trying to set Chrome as my default browser on my MacBook Air OS Mojave 10.14.06, and actually I've managed to do it but then [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc2mU.png) happens which I don't understand why (Chrome as a default browser on Chrome settings and System Preferences but not in "Open with"), and from time to time is causing me interference with other applications when suddenly I try to open a .html file for example, and instead of opening it with Chrome, it goes to Safari and due to the authorized developers permissions, it can't open it.

I tried clicking on "Other" and then choosing Chrome as "Open always with this app" but it still remains on Safari as default.

Also, I already tried with Chrome settings, System preferences (as you can see on the screenshot) and "Get Info", but none did the job.

Does anyone know how to definitively change it to Chrome?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem with Catalina and a Macbook pro but additionally in System Preferences I do not see any browsers listed at all.  Seems like a bug to me.